# Movie about good and bad "angels" with machine guns and black coats that came down to earth to kill each other?

Tags: story-identification, movie

When I was a kid (around 1990 - 1998), there was a movie about some type of "angels" with human bodies, weird eyes, and white hair? (excuse my poor memory), there were some good and some bad angels, and fight with machine guns and human weapons and dress with black coats and military boots? Their blood is white?

They came down to earth, to modern times in United States, in a city like LA or NY to do something and fight each other, and there were some regular human involved trying to help the good angels? Most of the movie happens in the night, scenarios are grey middle buildings and city slums, car chase, shooting, action, deaths, etc.

But I'm pretty sure they were angels, sent by God or something like this. A drama somehow similar to *Constantine* and *Legion*, but with the 90ish look of *Blade Runner*.

Anyone remember this movie? I think there was even several iterations, like part 1 and 2.

Comment: Probably not _[Dogma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogma_(film))_ but it's in the right time frame, and you have to start somewhere.

Comment: Arnold Schwarzenegger's "End of days"?

Comment: Were it not 10-20 years too late, I might say [*Legion*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6p01-in6-k).

Comment: _Blade Runner_ was 1982, not so 90-ish.

Comment: The description of the angels reminds me of the twins in Matrix Reloaded. But though some of the things you said match, many more don't. Too many to make it an answer.

Comment: @Spencer I also instantly thought "Dogma" but however delightful the idea, I was fairly sure it couldn't be.

Comment: @PrimeMover IIRC there were hockey sticks, not machine guns.

Comment: @Spencer ... and it was also the movie in which God played the part of Alannis Morisette. Oh, wait ...

Comment: @sujeto1 - If anyone correctly identifies the movie you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Perhaps you're thinking of ***[Dark Angel](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099817/)*** (1990), alternately titled *[I Come in Peace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Come_in_Peace)*.

From [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/IComeInPeace?from=Film.DarkAngel):

> *I Come in Peace* (1990) (released and known worldwide as *Dark Angel*) is a science fiction action thriller film about a rule-breaking vice cop who becomes involved in the investigation of a number of mysterious drug-related murders on the streets of Houston, Texas. The film was directed by Craig R Baxley, and stars Dolph Lundgren, Matthias Hues, Brian Benben, Betsy Brantley, and David Aykroyd. Future ESPN college basketball analyst Jay Bilas has a small role as an alien cop.
>
> Jack Caine (Lundgren) is a Houston cop who is determined to wipe out the White Boys, a gang of white-collar drug dealers who killed his partner while Caine was waylaid stopping a convenience store robbery. Little does he know that there is a new drug dealer in town (Matthias Hues), one who preys on heroin addicts in order to get his own drug of trade - made from the endorphins extracted from heroin users. But this guy's home turf isn't in Houston. It isn't even on planet Earth...

Things that don't match the description:

- Despite the title, there are no actual angels, only humans and two aliens.
- There are no sequels.

Things that do match:

- The film was released in 1990.
- The antagonist is an alien drug dealer with a human-like body, weird eyes, and white hair, wearing a black coat, and wielding a machine gun. He's pursued by another member of his species, who's dressed and armed the same way, but has dark hair, and is an officer of the law among their kind. So one is effectively 'good' and the other 'bad'.
- The good alien is wounded at one point in the film, and is shown to have white blood.
- The protagonist is a human cop who discovers that he and the good alien are on the same side.
- The film is set in the city of Houston, much of it at night.
- There's lots of shooting & action, multiple deaths, and one car chase sequence in the last twenty minutes of the film.
- As per the OP's comment [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/262337/movie-about-good-and-bad-angels-with-machine-guns-and-black-coats-that-came-do#comment722991_262338), both aliens can speak at least some English, but they only speak occasionally, and not with any humour or wit. Their demeanour is somewhat similar to that of the T-800 from the *The Terminator* (1984).

The film is up on YouTube. You can view a scene with the good alien opening fire on the bad alien with a machine gun at around the [30:30](https://youtu.be/uTk1EOkU6dA?t=1830) mark. You can view a similar scene, with the bad alien opening fire on the good one, at around the [50:22](https://youtu.be/uTk1EOkU6dA?t=3022) mark. And you can view the scene with the good alien bleeding white blood at around the [1:03:53](https://youtu.be/uTk1EOkU6dA?t=3833) mark.

Comment: That almost sounds like it stole a plot device from Liquid Sky, which featured ETs who harvested the endorphins of heroin highs and orgasms.

Comment: How I would *love* if people would stop calling any automatic weapon a "machine gun". [Machine guns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_gun) fire rifle cartridges. If it fires a pistol cartridge, it's a [*sub*machine gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submachine_gun). What we see in this movie is even less than that, more a [machine pistol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_pistol). This makes one hell of a difference, both for the one doing the shooting (weight, control) and the one being shot at (incoming firepower).

Comment: @DevSolar well, the weapon of the movie uses neither pistol nor rifle cartridges but magic cartridges which don’t need reloading and having adaptive penetration (as the plot needs) and apparently also being explosive when required. What real life category fits the most?

Comment: @Holger: Sounds like any regular movie handgun to me. ;-) But "machine gun" remains that pretty hefty thing with a bipod, usually belt-fed...

Comment: @DevSolar - I haven't watched the film all the way through, but from the clips I have viewed, those guns do appear to be of alien origin, and more powerful than terrestrial equivalents. In [this scene](https://youtu.be/uTk1EOkU6dA?t=4507), the white-haired alien seems unfazed by bullets fired from regular guns, whereas the alien bullets sent him running.

Comment: @LogicDictates yes, these specific guns are powered by alien magic, but DevSolar has a point about movie guns tending to have such traits in general.

Comment: I think this is the right one, but I remember it differently. I was like 5 years old. Great!

Answer (score 13):

This sounds like *[The Prophecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prophecy)*, which had four sequels.

> Thomas Dagget, a Catholic seminary student, loses his faith when he sees visions of a war between angels. Years later, Thomas is a detective with the Los Angeles Police Department. Two angels fall to Earth: Simon briefly enters Thomas' home and warns him of coming events, while Uziel, a lieutenant of the Archangel Gabriel, is killed in an altercation with Simon. Investigating the disturbance, Thomas finds in Simon's apartment the obituary of recently deceased Korean War veteran Colonel Arnold Hawthorne, and a thesis about angels which Thomas himself wrote in seminary. Meanwhile, in Chimney Rock, Arizona, Simon finds Hawthorne awaiting burial and sucks his soul out of his body.
>
> The medical examiner informs Thomas that Uziel's body has no eyes, hermaphroditism, and the blood chemistry of an aborted fetus. His personal effects include an ancient Bible, with an expanded Book of Revelation that describes a second war in Heaven and prophecy that a "dark soul" will be found on Earth and used as a weapon.
>
> Gabriel arrives on Earth. Needing a human helper, Gabriel catches a disappointed Jerry, a suicide, in the moment of his death. Jerry retrieves Uziel's belongings from the police station while Gabriel destroys Uziel's body in the morgue. Finding Hawthorne's obituary, Gabriel and Jerry head for Chimney Rock. Before Gabriel arrives, at the local reservation school Simon hides Hawthorne's soul in a little Native American girl, Mary, who immediately falls ill and is cared for by her teacher, Katherine.

### Trailer

Comment: It's definetly NOT this movie series , in the one I remember, angels were more robotic, more violents, way less elocuent, more like "Terminator", not sassy like Christopher Walken here. Maybe the one I reference is a B class already forgotten series, or my mind is making this up. Thanks for input.

Comment: The angels in the Prophecy didn't use guns or have white blood.

Comment: @Nu'Daq: I'll admit I don't remember about the guns, but I thought I remembered the white blood from the autopsy zone.

Comment: I don;t think it is a match, but thank you for another film with Christopher Walken :D

Answer (score 11):

You must be talking about Gabriel (2007), starring Andy Whitfield (RIP.)

To be clear why I think this fits (since the timing is off.)

- The movie takes place in an urban city in modern America EDIT: Correction - the city is "Purgatory" and most of the movie was actually filmed in abandoned buildings in Australia.
- The shots are mostly dark or nighttime
- There are angels and demons that fight with machine guns and wear black coats
- There is at least one character with white hair
- The main character is supported by mortals

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0857376/?ref_=nm_knf_i2

Comment: This can't really be it, it was made 10+ years after the OP mentioned they saw it.

Comment: @Erik time is a funny thing. So are false memories. There are a lot of matches in this movie to what was described. Better the OP finds the movie they _thought_ they saw in the '90s, than not, just because the expressed timing was off.

Comment: It is not this either. But how amazingly these one matches my "false memory", even tho I have never seen it.

Comment: @sujeto1 nothing in this world is new, and this is a good example of that. Stoked you found what you were looking for with the answer LogicDictates provided. :)

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is Fallen (2006) - [imdb page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0775362/?ref_=tt_urv)

Comment: Please explain why you think it's a match.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Note that this is approximately a decade after the range given in the question.